# Slideshow undefined

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Why is my code throwing this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

```js
var img = [
  "http://src.itec.systems/img/1.jpg",
  "http://src.itec.systems/img/2.jpg",
  "http://src.itec.systems/img/3.jpg"
];

var num = 0;

function sig() {
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  num++;
  if (num >= img.length) {
    num = 0;
  }
  slider.src.img[num];
}

function ant() {
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  num--;
  if (num < 0) {
    num = img.length - 1;
  }
  slider.src.img[num];
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="ant()">Anterior</button>
  <img id="slider" src="http://src.itec.systems/img/1.jpg">
  <button onclick="sig()">Siguiente</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `slider.src.img` is undefined.

Did you mean `slider.src = img[num]`?